# Select2 "change" event does not trigger htmx

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, htmx

This works, the way I want it: If the `<select>` gets changed, then [htmx](//htmx.org) gets triggered.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.1.0"></script>

<table>
 <tr hx-post="//example.com" hx-trigger="change">
  <td>
    <select name="runner">
     <option value="a">a</option>
     <option value="b">b</option>
    </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

If I use a django-autocomplete-light widget, then it does not work.

I use this version: django-autocomplete-light==3.8.1

Comment: can you add "select" as an hx-trigger as well as the change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I add this JS, then it works. Better solutions are welcome.

```
<script>
 window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
  $('select').on('select2:select', function (e) {
   $(this).closest('tr').get(0).dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});
 })
</script>
```

Answer (score 12):

Just come across this same issue, and fixed it with the following modified version of guettli's answer.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
    $('select').on('select2:select', function (e) {
        $(this).closest('select').get(0).dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    });
});
```

Comment: I had to tigger the change event on the element with hx-trigger attribute.

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked when also adding `htmx.onLoad()` using bootstrap 5 styled Select2 https://apalfrey.github.io/select2-bootstrap-5-theme/:

```js
htmx.onLoad(() => {
   $("#collection-select").select2({
      theme: "bootstrap-5",
      closeOnSelect: true
   });
});
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
   $('select').on('select2:select', function (e) {
      $(this).closest('select').get(0).dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to trigger the change event with the htmx javascript API `trigger` https://htmx.org/api/#trigger

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
  $('select').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    htmx.trigger($(this).closest('select').get(0), 'change')
  })
})
```